# What is dependency-based init system?

Tags: init, gnu-shepherd

My knowledge about init is limited. All the things I know is that init is the first process that kernel starts after getting booted and is assigned with Process ID of 1.

> [image]

Recently while going through [GNU Shepherd](https://www.gnu.org/software/shepherd/), I noticed the following sentence.

> It provides a replacement for the service-managing capabilities of SysV-init (or any other init) with a both powerful and beautiful **dependency-based system** with a convenient interface.

So, I want to know what is meant by dependency-based system here? Is it the feature that distinguish it with popular SysV or Sysmted init systems?

Answer (score 2):

Dependency-based init systems are systems where the order in which services are initialised is based on dependency information provided inside or alongside the services. This is in contrast with init systems where the order is determined statically (typically by relying on lexicographical order, as in the diagram you included in your question).

Some systems can mix both approaches; for example on Debian systems using `sysvinit`, a dependency-based layer on top of `sysvinit` uses LSB headers in the init scripts to calculate the initialisation order, and stores it by naming the `/etc/rc?.d/` symlinks as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people get this wrong.  Some of the answers here are even getting it wrong.

First, let's clear up some misnomers:

- The distinction between a program named `init` that runs as process #1 and a program named `rc` that runs as another process goes back all the way to First Edition Unix.  Most of what you are discussing *isn't done by process #1* in the overwhelming majority of service/system management softwares, Upstart and systemd being *exceptions* rather than the rule.
- "sysvinit" isn't AT&T Unix System 5 `init`+`rc`.  It's a clone `init` and `rc` system written originally for Minix by Miquel van Smoorenburg, ironically some years after AT&T Unix System 5 itself *largely did away with* that system, replacing it with something called the Service Access Facility.

What you are asking about is *service management*, the task of the aforementioned Service Access Facility (SAF) on AT&T Unix, the AIX System Resource Controller (SRC), the Solaris Service Management Facility (SMF), systemd, Upstart, daemontools, daemontools-encore, runit, nosh toolset service management, s6, and a whole bunch of other toolsets.
The original AT&T Unix System 5 `rc`, before the SAF and SRC came along, had just forked off the service processes directly and didn't really *manage* them thereafter.

The van Smoorenburg `rc` on Linux (from Minix) still did this.
Moreover, it originally relied upon manual and rather ad hoc ordering of service startups/shutdowns with respect to one another.
The original giant single `rc` script, which went through several mutations in the 1970s and early 1980s that one can still find fossilized here and there (in the likes of `rc.local`), by the time of the van Smoorenburg `rc` clone in the 1990s had become a set of *drop-in* scripts in a subdirectory of `/etc/` and some symbolic link farms (in other subdirectories of `/etc/`) that represented the order that those scripts were run in in order to do the overall `rc` task.
The symbolic link farms were based around a priority scheme, where the different `rc` scripts were assigned priorities from 0 to 99.
(There was an alternative mechanism to the symbolic link farm in the late 1990s, file-rc, but it too used a priority system.)
This was a pain to administer, because there were no universal conventions on choices of priority, and because of the "two softwares both want to be first" problem.
(Ironically, you can see [someone who is using a fossil way of doing things asking about one of the related problems on this very WWW site *just yesterday*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/596886/5132).)

*Dependency-based service management* tries to do better.
Service definitions, in whatever form they come in, list what services each service *depends from* and *should be ordered relative to* when starting up and shutting down.
There is no "first" and "last", but there are *before* and *after*, as well as *needs* and *conflicts with*.

It has been in the old `rc`-style systems on Linux and the BSDs for most of the 21st century.

- Mewburn `rc` and OpenRC (both 21st century inventions) learned from the systems that came before them, and incorporated a means of expressing interdependencies between the different `rc` scripts from the start.  In Mewburn `rc`, a system of comments in the various `rc` scripts (e.g. `REQUIRE`, `PROVIDE`, and `BEFORE`) expresses the interdependencies amongst services, and a program named `rcorder` calculates from them the order to run things in at the start of every bootstrap/shutdown.
- van Smoorenburg `rc` gained a program called `insserv` from Debian people.  Interdependencies were expressed among services by a system of conventional "LSB headers" included as comments in the various `rc` scripts, and the priorities were rewritten in the symbolic links by `insserv` at software installation/deinstallation time, to reflect the dependencies.  This was fairly heavily adopted by Debian and some of its derivatives in the latter part of the first decade of the 21st century.  See [the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/DependencyBasedBoot) for more.

It moreover existed as a first-class mechanism in many of the non-`rc` service managers, from Solaris SMF to systemd, from the outset.
Notable exceptions were Upstart, daemontools (and daemontools-encore, perp, and runit), and (years ago) s6.

daemontools, runit, et al. all originally took the "giant thundering herd" approach to the problem, starting and restarting services over and over until they all stayed up.
Some tweaked this slightly with tricks, such as programs that made services pause and not invoke their main service programs until something else happened, but the basic idea remained that *everything in an entire "scan" directory* got started all at once.

I long maintained that one could do better than this, with some layering on top of the base service management, and eventually demonstrated this with [a concrete toolset that did so](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/), taking the startup "scan" logic out of the actual service manager, moving it into a separate program, and building a system of service bundle interdependencies around the base daemontools service/supervise directory structures.
Laurent Bercot also demonstrated the same with additions to s6 named [s6-rc](https://skarnet.org/software/s6-rc/).
Even OpenRC demonstrates this, as its `rc` scripts express interdependencies and can be made to employ an external service manager (such as s6).

Upstart, ironically for what some people thought in the 2010s, was actually envisioned (back around 2005) as the *new* way of doing service management, to *replace* dependency-based service management with *event-based* service management, where services were started in response to *events happening* rather than as the result of *calculating an ordered set of dependencies*.
It's beyond the scope of this answer to discuss why that concept was eventually rejected, and people *went back* to dependency-based service management, but it is important to realize that by the start of the 2010s dependency-based service management was *the norm*.
Upstart developers had regarded it as old hat.
van Smoorenburg `rc` had it via the Debian work, albeit that Fedora and SUSE didn't really pick that up from Debian.
Mewburn `rc` and OpenRC had it from the outset.
systemd was just about to be invented with it.
Solaris, Illumos, et al. had it with the SMF.
And so forth.

This isn't a distinguishing feature, except from the likes of runit and Upstart.
It was and is the norm.
This is something that other people had already done, or were doing, even at the inception of GNU Shepherd.
GNU dmd, now known as GNU Shepherd, was invented in 2003.
Debian had begun the move to `insserv` in 2002; Richard Gooch had written about `need` in 2002; Mewburn `rc` was invented in 2000, and Luke Mewburn's original paper on the subject explains how expressing dependencies with something better than a priority system encoded in filenames was a design feature.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018).  [*`/etc/rc.local` is a thing of the past.*](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/rc.local-is-history.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). *[The known problems with System 5 `rc`](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/system-5-rc-problems.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018).  [*The Unix Service Access Facility*](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/unix-service-access-facility.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- V.R. (2015-09-05). *[A history of modern init systems (1992–2015)](https://blog.darknedgy.net/technology/2015/09/05/0/)*.  darknedgy.net.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, +1 ; It will take some time for me to read and understand your full answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it the feature that distinguish it with popular SysV or Sysmted init systems?

Well, not from [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/), which "implements an elaborate transactional *dependency-based* service control logic" (emphasis mine).

I'll quote Lennart Poettering's [rationale for systemd](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd.html) here:

> All these units can have dependencies between each other (both
> positive and negative, i.e. 'Requires' and 'Conflicts'): a device can
> have a dependency on a service, meaning that as soon as a device
> becomes available a certain service is started. Mounts get an implicit
> dependency on the device they are mounted from. Mounts also gets
> implicit dependencies to mounts that are their prefixes (i.e. a mount
> /home/lennart implicitly gets a dependency added to the mount for
> /home) and so on.

In the old sysv era, there was no first-class way of expressing dependencies between systems services. It was shoe-horned in using ordering of the scripts, commit headers and such, but such a system is naturally fragile. This makes it particularly hard to order things right (e.g., this service needs this network interface and this mount point to be up, but the mount point requires  some other device to be up and so on - think of ordering that by hand using the numerical prefixes of scripts in `/etc/rcX.D/`).

By having a proper system to express dependencies between units, one can get the init system to come up with a proper ordering, since it has all the information regarding how services relate to each other and the system.

---

To contrast and compare, consider Upstart, which, instead of using dependencies directly, relied on events:

> Upstart does service serialization via these events: if the
> syslog-started event is triggered this is used as an indication to
> start D-Bus since it can now make use of Syslog. And then, when
> dbus-started is triggered, NetworkManager is started, since it may now
> use D-Bus, and so on.
>
> One could say that this way the actual logical dependency tree that
> exists and is understood by the admin or developer is translated and
> encoded into event and action rules: every logical "a needs b" rule
> that the administrator/developer is aware of becomes a "start a when b
> is started" plus "stop a when b is stopped".

Comment: Your comments about sysvinit are not really about sysvinit, they're about the `init.d` approach used by most LSB-compliant distros prior to systemd being introduced. Gentoo for example uses sysvinit with OpenRC and has none of these issues (OpenRC handles the dependency tracking at runtime as an implicit part of the init scripts, not through headers that only get examined to update script names).

Answer (score 0):

'Dependency-based' in this context means it looks at what services actually need functionality provided by other services, usually at runtime, and usually with zero user intervention, as opposed to relying on other factors to determine ordering of service startup 9such as lexical ordering of filenames).

This is in contrast to the original SVR4 init arrangement, the `init.d` approach used by most Linux distros prior to the advent of systemd, and some older BSD `rc.d` approaches, all of which require the user/admin to manually provide the ordering of services for startup, either by setting file names or variables by hand, or by running a tool to do so by scanning for metadata embedded in the scripts.

Examples of other dependency-based `init` and service supervision systems in active use today include:

- OpenRC: Used by Alpine and Gentoo. Uses a special function definition and macros in the init script itself to obtain dependency information (which is actually rather powerful, because you can express conditional dependencies between services, such as LVM setup only needing `lvmetad` to be running if it's enabled in the LVM configuration), and supports 'generic' dependencies (such as needing a running syslog daemon, but not caring which one is running).
- Monit: A service supervisor that can replace `init` in some cases. Does runtime dependency computations based on dependencies defined for the entities it monitors ('entities' instead of services in this case because you can monitor and depend on things like external services elsewhere on the network or files and directories on the system, not just services).
- Upstart: An older replacement `init` system from Ubuntu. Upstart did not do dependency tracking directly, but instead had services trigger state changes based on events, which was then used to provide what is effectively dependency-based ordering of service startup.
- Systemd: The current type example of dependency-based ordering (often claimed incorrectly to be the first such `init` system by it's fanboys). Does the dependency calculations at runtime and provides some features that actually mitigate the need for strict dependency tracking in some cases.