# fluxbox inside rc.local startup script sometimes does not spawn process and start

Tags: linux, shell-script, startup, fluxbox, rc.local

This issue is driving me crazy. I have no clue why it sometimes happens. Its totally feeling intermittent.

I have a `/etc/rc.local` shell script that fires off on startup.
I am using `Ubuntu x64 19.10`... For what its worth, I run this off a cloud droplet via Digital Ocean.

Long story short...

My script has at the beginning something like this...

```
echo "Starting virtual display session..."
export DISPLAY=:0
Xvfb :0 -screen 0 640x360x16 & 
DISPLAY=:0.0 fluxbox &
sleep 1
x11vnc -display :0.0 -usepw -forever -bg
```

All of this works most of the time....

However the `fluxbox` sometimes just will not load. I will end up with a X display session but no window manager. When I run `ps aux | grep fluxbox` I see nada.

The issue is that it only happens sometimes. I can reboot the system and most of the time it will load, but on occasion it just totally does not start process.

UPDATE: I can see the following error happen when this seems to occur:

```
Error: Couldn't connect to XServer:0.0
```

Why is this happening if I am setting the export of the display and also setting the display when I start the fluxbox process?

Does anyone have any idea?

Note: I only have the virtual frame buffer via xvfb and it always runs on `DISPLAY=:0`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Xvfb :0 -screen 0 640x360x16 & 
> DISPLAY=:0.0 fluxbox &
> ```

This is simple enough.  You've forked off two processes to run in parallel.  The `Xvfb` program hasn't finished initializing by the time that the `fluxbox` program gets to the point of trying to connect to an X server.  You have a multitasking operating system, no doubt a multiprocessor machine, and a non-deterministic load at bootstrap.  Race conditions like this exist unless you take steps to avoid/prevent them.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018).  [*`/etc/rc.local` is a thing of the past.*](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/rc.local-is-history.html).  Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: How can i avoid race condition? Should i just use `&&`

E.g:


Xvfb :0 -screen 0 640x360x16 && DISPLAY=:0.0 fluxbox &